# Indirect modification of overloaded element of App\Models\ has no effect

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I’m getting this error: Indirect modification of overloaded element of App\Models\ has no effect, change ->get(); to ->first->toArray(); another error Call to a member function toArray() on null

here the code

```
$penjualan   = Penjualan::find(session('id_penjualan'));
$detail      = PenjualanDetail::with('produk')->where('id_penjualan', session('id_penjualan'))->get();
$transaction = new Penjualan();

        foreach ($detail as $item) {
            $transaction_details = [
                'order_id'     => $penjualan->id_penjualan,
                'gross_amount' => $penjualan->bayar,
            ];
    
            $item_details = [
                'id'       => $penjualan->id_penjualan,
                'price'    => $item->harga_jual,
                'quantity' => $item->jumlah,
                'name'     => $item->produk->nama_produk,
            ];
    
            $customer_details  = [
                'first_name' => $request->get('uname'),
                'last_name'  => '',
                'email'      => $request->get('email'),
                'phone'      => $request->get('number'),            
            ];
    
            $transaction = [
                'transaction_details'  => $transaction_details,
                'item_details'         => $item_details,
                'customer_details'     => $customer_details,
            ];
        }
 
        $snapToken = Midtrans\Snap::getSnapToken($transaction);
        $transaction->snap_token = $snapToken;
        $transaction->save();
```

anyone could help me to fix this?

Comment: try to add relation between Penjualan and PenjualanDetail? for example add in Penjualan   model function details() , and call it when $penjualan is not empty , $penjualan->details

Comment: for $transaction , please use array instead of new Penjualan(), and at the end use Penjualan::create($transaction);  .... Semoga membantu (: translated to hope this help you)

Comment: this is actually a payment gateway integration add a relation between penjualan and transaction, then request for a snap token which is using webhook API request. Problem is I understand what causing the error and what logic for API request for backend implementation

Comment: you understand the problem but no solution yet? have a look at this tutorials https://jurnalmms.web.id/laravel/integrasi-midtrans-dan-laravel-bagian-1/ , perhaps can help you integrating MidTrans payment

Answer (score 0):

I have done Midtrans payment before.
The problem you've got with your current code are

- you want to store snap_token inside your Penjualan model, but you use new Penjualan()
- when multiple items are ordered, your code do not support it cause $item_details is a single array inside foreach loop

So here is an updated code with some notes and recommendations.

```
$id = session('id_penjualan');

$validated = $request->validate([
  'uname'   => 'required|string',
  // 'lname'    => 'nullable|string',
  'email'   => 'required|string',
  'number'  => 'required|string',
]);

// use single query to retrieve Penjualan and PenjualanDetail
// for product name, recommend to store it within PenjualanDetail, along with price and base_price
$penjualan = Penjualan::query()
    ->with('details')
    ->find($id);

if (!$penjualan) {
  // you can redirect your customer to cart or any other page
  return redirect('cart')->with('error', 'Can not find Penjualan.');
}

$item_details = [];

foreach ($penjualan->details as $item) {
    $item_details[] = [
        'id'       => $item->id,
        'price'    => $item->harga_jual,
        'quantity' => $item->jumlah,
        // recommended product's name to be stored within PenjualanDetail
        'name'     => $item->nama_produk,
    ];
}

$transaction_details = [
    'order_id'      => $penjualan->id_penjualan,
    // "bayar" must not contain any decimal, use cast Money
    'gross_amount'  => $penjualan->bayar,
];

// Optional
$customer_details  = [
    'first_name' => $validated['uname'],
    'last_name'  => '', // $validated['lname'],
    'email'      => $validated['email'],
    'phone'      => $validated['number'],    
    // 'billing_address' => '',
    // 'shipping_address' => '',
];

// this is a simple array that will be sent to method getSnapToken()
$transaction = [
    'transaction_details'  => $transaction_details,
    'customer_details'     => $customer_details,
    'item_details'         => $item_details,
];

// this method only accept good old array
$snapToken = Midtrans\Snap::getSnapToken($transaction);

$penjualan->snap_token = $snapToken;

// recommend to store your customer detail here, either multiple fields or single array field storing $customer_details

// $penjualan->first_name = $customer_details['first_name'];
// $penjualan->last_name = $customer_details['last_name'];
// $penjualan->email = $customer_details['email'];
// $penjualan->phone = $customer_details['phone'];
// $penjualan->billing_address = $customer_details['billing_address'];
// $penjualan->shipping_address = $customer_details['shipping_address'];

$penjualan->save();
```

I commented out some parts that you might not use, where I did used them in the past.

Feel free to adjust them to suite your needs.

Comment: edit code to this:                                                                                                                     $id    = session('id_penjualan');
$detail      = DB::table('penjualan_detail')->get();
$transaction = new Penjualan;  error: array_replace_recursive(): Argument #2 must be of type array, App\Models\Penjualan given. error point to this: $snapToken = \Midtrans\Snap::getSnapToken($transaction);

Comment: getSnapToken only accept plain simple array, so what you need to do is declare $transaction = array() , and if you want to save snap_token into Penjualan, use Penjualan::where()->update([snap_token => $token])

Comment: Have a good look at my code , I have added extra comments before $transction = [ ... ] and before $snapToken = Midtrans... , I hope you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function getSnapToken ()
    { 
        $id             = session('id_penjualan');
        $member         = Member::orderBy('nama')->get();
        $penjualan      = Penjualan::with(['penjualan_detail' => $detail = function ($query) {
                            $query->where('item', 'kode_produk, subtotal, jumlah, nama_produk');
                            }])->where('id_penjualan', ('id_penjualan'))
                            ->orderBy('id_penjualan')
                            ->get();
        $transaction    = array($penjualan);

        foreach ( $detail as $item ) {
            $transaction_details = [
                'order_id'     => $this->penjualan->id_penjualan,
                'gross_amount' => $this->penjualan->bayar,
            ];

            $item_details  = [
                'id'       => $item->produk->kode_produk,
                'price'    => $item->jumlah * $item->subtotal,
                'quantity' => $item->jumlah,
                'name'     => $item->produk->nama_produk,
            ];

            $customer_details  = [
                'id'         => $penjualan->member->kode_member,  
                'first_name' => $validated['uname'],
                'last_name'  => $validated['lname'],
                'email'      => $validated['email'],
                'phone'      => $validated['number'], 
                // 'billing_address' => '',
                // 'shipping_address' => '',          
            ];       

            $transaction = [
                'transaction_details'  => $transaction_details,
                'item_details'         => $item_details,
                'customer_details'     => $customer_details,
            ];
        }

        $snap_token = '';
        try {
            $snap_token = \Midtrans\Snap::getSnapToken($transaction);
        }
         catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        } 

        echo "snap_token = ".$snap_token;
    }

  public function payment(Penjualan $penjualan)
    {
        $snap_token = $penjualan->snap_token;
            if (is_null($snap_token)) {
    
                $midtrans   = new CreateSnapTokenService($penjualan);
                $snap_token = $midtrans->getSnapToken();
    
                $snap_token = Penjualan::where('id_penjualan')->update(['snap_token' => $snap_token]);
            }

        return view('penjualan.payment', ['snap_token'=>$snap_token]);
    }
```